Is there a way to make the visual effect of linear gradient colors in SVG and CSS the same?
I found that the visual effect of the linear gradient color is different between SVG and CSS, especially in the adjacent part between two colors. I want to know if this is due to differences in linear interpolation. And is there a solution to make the effect of the SVG the same as the CSS?


#rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(235, 116, 116, 0.1) 0%, rgba(42, 255, 44, 1) 100%);
}

.stop1 {
  stop-color: rgba(235, 116, 116);
  stop-opacity: 0.1;
}

.stop2 {
  stop-color: rgba(42, 255, 44, 1);
}


/* added by editor for comparrison reasons */

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.25em;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>CSS</p>
    <div id='rectangle'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <p>SVG</p>
    <svg width="800" height="800" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1" spreadMethod="repeat">
          <stop class="stop1" offset="0%" />
          <stop class="stop2" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" rx="0" ry="0" width="100" height="300" fill="url(#Gradient1)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>




Get rid of the opacity and this behaves normally, this is interesting

Yes, that seems to be correct. Firefox supports color-interpolation on gradients and I believe Chrome will do so soon too.


#rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(235, 116, 116, 0.1) 0%, rgba(42, 255, 44, 1) 100%);
}

.stop1 {
  stop-color: rgba(235, 116, 116);
  stop-opacity: 0.1;
}

.stop2 {
  stop-color: rgba(42, 255, 44, 1);
}


/* added by editor for comparrison reasons */

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.25em;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>CSS</p>
    <div id='rectangle'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <p>SVG</p>
    <svg width="800" height="800" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="Gradient1" color-interpolation="linearRGB" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1" spreadMethod="repeat">
          <stop class="stop1" offset="0%" />
          <stop class="stop2" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" rx="0" ry="0" width="100" height="300" fill="url(#Gradient1)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for answering! I found that the visual effect of the answer is still different on my side (Edge/Firefox/Chrome). T_T I searched and found that the default color interpolation for CSS is sRGB, and that the color-interpolation attribute in SVG can be set to sRGB. And I tried it, unfortunately, the visual effect between them is still different. T_T

While there's a pronounced difference in Chrome indicating that it doesn't yet support linearrgb it looks the same to me in Firefox.

Thanks again! I downloaded the latest Firefox, and I saw the visual effects of them are the same.

But I need to support the same visual effect in Edge  (._.) . Based on the current discussion, it may not be implementable.

Other browsers such as Chrome and Safari seem to be working on adding support. Latest I saw was that it's expected to be in Chrome 127
